# Integration of SQL Server with visual studios

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ssis

I am going to start using SQL server with Asp.net using Microsoft Visual Studios 10.
 I am facing a problem that first when I install visual studio 10 and try to make a sample web aplication then it runs fine, but then I go on "add new item" then "SQL Server Database" then it shows me that you should first install SQL server 2005/2008 Express.

When I install it now SQL database is added in my web application, but when I write click on tables and click on "add new table" it shows me a popup that "Could not find assembly of library Microsodt.sqlserver.Management.sdk.sfc , version-10.0.0.0 ... " 
I am using windows 7 32 bit operating system 
 please help me in this regards I got stuck in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought - did you only install the database server, or did you install the SQL Management Studio portion as well. The easiest thing to do will probably be to install SSMS if you haven't. (You may want to make sure you've picked any extras.)

If that doesn't cover it it may be worth looking at this link on [MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30440). Its not something I've ever needed to install though.

Comment: Try this link http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22985 - Once you have SSMS installed, you can access it via localhost and you should be set.

Comment: @user1615206: above comment is out of date - I re-authored the answer.

Comment: i cant understand wot u trying me to do... have download wot ever in this link and install but problem is still same... rite click on table that error appears again and again...